# A small but expandable Exam system

Tags: java, object-oriented, swing, quiz

I'm trying to practice OO design as well as OOP in Java so I've created an Exam system that tries to be Object Oriented and expandable.
This is what I **haven't learned from Java so far:** Java 8, interfaces, Collections, IO, Swing, exceptions

```
public abstract class Question {
    protected int score;
    protected boolean isAnswerRight;

    public Question(int puntuacion) {
        this.score = puntuacion;
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public abstract void ask();

    public abstract void showClue();

}
```

This class has two children

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultipleOptionQuestion extends Question {
    private static final int MULTIPLE_OPTION_SCORE = 1;
    private String statement;
    private String[] options;
    private String clue;
    private int rightOption;

    public MultipleOptionQuestion(int score, String statement, String[] options, int rightOption, String clue) {
        super(MULTIPLE_OPTION_SCORE);
        this.statement = statement;
        this.options = options;
        this.clue = clue;
        this.rightOption = rightOption;
    }

    @Override
    public void ask() {
        String answer = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, statement, "Question Test", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
        if (answer.equals(options[rightOption])) {
            this.isAnswerRight = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void showClue() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, clue);

    }
}
```

And an abstract class to represent simple math operations (+,-,*,/)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class ArithmeticQuestion extends Question {


    //additions may have a wider interval in order to make them harder
    // than multiplications, for example, and we want divisions to be exact so
    //child classes provide operands
    protected int first;
    protected int second;
    protected int result;


    public int getFirstOperand() {
        return first;
    }

    public int getSecondOperand() {
        return second;
    }

    public int getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public abstract char getOperator();


    public ArithmeticQuestion(int score) {
        super(score);
    }

    public String stringQuestion() {
        return "How much is it? " +
                getFirstOperand() +
                getOperator() +
                getSecondOperand();
    }

    @Override
    public void ask() {
        String answer = null;
        while (answer == null || answer.equals("")) {
            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, this.stringQuestion());
            if (answer != null) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(answer) == getResult()) {
                    isAnswerRight = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(isAnswerRight ? "Right" : "Wrong"); //For debugging
    }

}
```

**Here is where I'm not sure I have made a good design** (I don't know whether I have too many classes)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class AdditionQuestion extends ArithmeticQuestion {

    private static final int ADDITION_MINIMUM = 100;
    private static final int ADDITION_INTERVAL = 200;
    private static final int ADDITION_SCORE = 1;

    public AdditionQuestion() {
        super(ADDITION_SCORE);
        this.first = (int) (Math.random() * ADDITION_INTERVAL) + ADDITION_MINIMUM;
        this.second = (int) (Math.random() * ADDITION_INTERVAL) + ADDITION_MINIMUM;
        this.result = first + second;
    }

    @Override
    public char getOperator() {
        return '+';
    }

    @Override
    public void showClue() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Be careful when you add more than 10 units");
    }
}
```

The class for Subtraction

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class SubtractionQuestion extends ArithmeticQuestion {
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_MINIMUM = 0;
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_INTERVAL = 100;
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_SCORE = 1;

    public SubtractionQuestion() {
        super(SUBTRACTION_SCORE);
        this.first = (int) (Math.random() * SUBTRACTION_INTERVAL) + SUBTRACTION_MINIMUM;
        this.second = (int) (Math.random() * SUBTRACTION_INTERVAL) + SUBTRACTION_MINIMUM;
        this.result = first - second;
    }

    @Override
    public char getOperator() {
        return '-';
    }

    @Override
    public void showClue() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The answer may be a negative number");
    }

}
```

For multiplication

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class MultiplicationQuestion extends ArithmeticQuestion {
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_MINIMUM = 1;
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_INTERVAL = 10;
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_SCORE = 3;


    public MultiplicationQuestion() {
        super(MULTIPLICATION_SCORE);
        this.first = (int) (Math.random() * MULTIPLICATION_INTERVAL) + MULTIPLICATION_MINIMUM;
        this.second = (int) (Math.random() * MULTIPLICATION_INTERVAL) + MULTIPLICATION_MINIMUM;
        this.result = first * second;
    }

    @Override
    public char getOperator() {
        return '*';
    }

    @Override
    public void showClue() {
        String output = "RECALL THE MULTIPLICATION TABLE\n";
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            output += i + "x" + getFirstOperand() + "=" + i * getSecondOperand() + "\n";
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
    }
}
```

And finally, the exams:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public abstract class Exam {
    protected Question[] questions = new Question[50];
    protected int currentNumberOfQuestions = 0;
    protected int totalScore = 0;

    public void addQuestion(Question p) {
        questions[currentNumberOfQuestions++] = p;
    }

    public void increaseScore(int score) {
        this.totalScore += score;
    }

    public int maximumPossibleScore() {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < currentNumberOfQuestions; i++) {
            total += questions[i].getScore();
        }
        return total;
    }

    public void examResult() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You've got " + this.totalScore + " points out of: " + maximumPossibleScore());
    }

    public abstract void doExam();
}
```

A mock exam (makes the same question until you are right)

```
public class mockExam extends Exam {
    //The student only scores if they are right in their first attempt
    //If they are wrong, a clue is shown

    @Override
    public void doExam() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.currentNumberOfQuestions; i++) {
            Question p = this.questions[i];
            p.ask();
            if (p.isAnswerRight) {
                this.increaseScore(p.score);
            }
            while (!p.isAnswerRight) {
                p.showClue();
                p.ask();
            }
        }
        examResult();
    }
}
```

And a real Exam

```
public class RealExamen extends Exam {
    //Only asks each question once
    @Override
    public void doExam() {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.currentNumberOfQuestions; i++) {
            Question p = this.questions[i];
            p.ask();
            if (p.isAnswerRight) {
                this.increaseScore(p.score);
            }
        }
        examResult();
    }
}
```

Looking to hear your feedback on how I can improve and manage my code.

Comment: `This class has two childs` This class has two *children,* please!  On you main question:  given your current code, I'd guess that one class per arithmetic operator is too much.  However certain designs (like an interpreter) do exactly as you are doing now, so if the overall code was more complex it might be an advantage to have each operator with its own class.  Everything depends, there are no hard and fast rules.

Comment: This class has two childs This class has two children, please! Sorry. I have corrected the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank for sharing your code.

## OOP doesn't mean to "split up" code into random classes.

The ultimate goal of OOP is to reduce code duplication, improve readability and support reuse as well as extending the code.

Doing OOP means that you follow certain principles which are (among others):

- information hiding / encapsulation
- single responsibility
- separation of concerns
- KISS (Keep it simple (and) stupid.)
- DRY (Don't repeat yourself.)
- "Tell! Don't ask."
- Law of demeter ("Don't talk to strangers!")
- replace branching with polymorphism

### Information hiding

This is a major principle (not only in OOP). In OOP this means that no other class (not even sub classes) know the inner structure of a certain class.

You violate this principle by giving the  sub classes of `Question` direct access to its member variables `score` and `isAnswerRight`.

This also violates the *Tell, don't ask!* principle.

The better approach would be to add a method to class `Question` to manage the `score` value itself:

```
public abstract class Question {
    private final /*hopefully the score never change during runtime */
                   int score; 

    public Question(int puntuacion) {
        this.score = puntuacion;
    }

   /** public entry point, do not override */
    public final int ask(){
          boolean isAnsweredRight = askUser();
          if(!isAnsweredRight) {// may fail once
              showClue();
              isAnsweredRight = askUser();
           }
           return isAnsweredRight? score : 0; // no score if failed
    };

    /** ask the question and report success/failure */
    protected abstract boolean askUser();

    public abstract void showClue();
}
```

## class design

As mentioned in the comments some Subclasses of `Question` raise doubt:

In OOP we create new (sub)classes when we need to change *behavior*. That is: we overwrite a method of the super class to do some different or additional *calculation*. (returning a value is no calculation...)

I argue the reasoning in the comment: The fact that a bad design is done somewhere else should not be an excuse to do the same.

So I would have only two subclasses of `Question`:

```
public class MultipleOptionQuestion extends Question {
```

and

```
public class ArithmeticQuestion extends Question {
```

I would introduce another interface `Operation` like this:

```
interface Operation{
    int calculate(int first, int second);
}
```

And the `ArithmeticQuestion` would look like this:

```
public class ArithmeticQuestion extends Question {
    private final int first;
    private final int second;
    private final Operation operation;
    private final String operator;
    private final String clue;

    public ArithmeticQuestion(String operator, Operation operation, in first, int second, int score, String clue)
       super(score);
       // constructors do no work, they just assign values to members
       this.operation=operation;
       this.operator=operator;
       this.first=first;
       this.second=second;
       this.clue=clue;
   }
    public String stringQuestion() {
        return "How much is it? " +
                first +
                operator +
                second;
    }    

    public void showClue() {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, clue);
    }   

    @Override
    public boolean askUser() {
        int result = operation.calculate(first,second);
        String answer = null;
        while (answer == null || answer.equals("")) {
            answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, this.stringQuestion());
            if (answer != null) {
                return Integer.parseInt(answer) == result;
            }
        }
        return false; // maybe marked as unreachable code...
    }

}
```

this would lead to this exsam class:

```
public class Exam {
    private static final int MULTIPLE_OPTION_SCORE = 1;
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_MINIMUM = 1;
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_INTERVAL = 10;
    private static final int MULTIPLICATION_SCORE = 3;
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_MINIMUM = 0;
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_INTERVAL = 100;
    private static final int SUBTRACTION_SCORE = 1;
    private static final int ADDITION_MINIMUM = 100;
    private static final int ADDITION_INTERVAL = 200;
    private static final int ADDITION_SCORE = 1;
    private static final int QUESTION_TYPE_COUNT = 4;


    public void doExam(int numberOfQuestions) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int maxScore =0;
        int userScore =0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++) {
            int questionType =random.nextInt(QUESTION_TYPE_COUNT);
            Question question;
            switch(questionType){
              case 0: // Addition
                  question = new ArithmeticQuestion("+",
                     (first,second)->first+second,
                     random.nextInt(ADDITION_INTERVAL)+ADDITION_MINIMUM,
                     random.nextInt(ADDITION_INTERVAL)+ADDITION_MINIMUM,
                     ADDITION_SCORE,
                     "Be careful when you add more than 10 units");
                   maxScore+=ADDITION_SCORE;
                   break;
                case 1: // Subtraction
                  question = new ArithmeticQuestion("-",
                     (first,second)->first-second,
                     random.nextInt(SUBTRACTION_INTERVAL)+SUBTRACTION_MINIMUM,
                     random.nextInt(SUBTRACTION_INTERVAL)+SUBTRACTION_MINIMUM,
                     SUBTRACTION_SCORE,
                     "The answer may be a negative number");
                   maxScore+=SUBTRACTION_SCORE;
                   break;
                case 2: // Multiplication
                  // ...
                default: // MultiOption
                  // ...
              }      
              userScore+= question.ask();
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You reached "+userScore+ " of "+maxScore+" possible points!")
    }
}
```

Comment: About Information Hiding I absolutely agree with you. There are mistakes I should have noticed. About class desing I understand your point but I think you use interfaces and lambda expressions, subjects I haven't seen yet. Moreover the final doExam method has a big, hard to read and maintain switch statement  that I guess will grow as new kinds of questions are added. I don't want to argue with you, I'm asking for clarification on this point. Thanks for your complete review and the time you spent on it, I really appreciate.

Comment: *"I think you use interfaces and lambda expressions"* right, its a simplification in Java8, - *"final doExam method has a big, hard to read and maintain switch statement that I guess will grow as new kinds of questions are added."* as a next step I'd convert that switch into an `enum`...

Answer (score 3):

My point of view (which certainly overlaps with timothy's explanations):

### Abstraction

I really dislike abstraction, I'd treat it - as it is said in german - "step-motherly". You have an abstract type `Question`, an abstract type `MultipleOptionQuestion` which extends `Question` and overwrites `ask()` and `showClue()`, a class `ArithmeticQuestion`which extends `Question` and provides additional methods. And several other `Question` types which override and extend behaviour. And this is, to put it mildly, a bit of a mess. Beside the mess, you can't test logic in your abstract type *without* an actual implementation, nor can you test your implementation *without* abstraction, *except* you're very strict about decoupling abstraction and implementation. And the could also violate Liskov's substitution principle, more about this later:

### Coupling of Question and GUI

Your Question types have a *direct dependency* to swing classes. If you would want to change the gui, or use another technology, maybe an app, or a web page, you *have to change* the business logic. The GUI is usually the top part of a multi tier architecture, and calls the layer below it, and the layer below must not know about the GUI.

### Liksov's substitution principle

Now, this is especially important, if you implement the 'coupling' part above. The principle is the following: You have a routine A. A performs something with the 'supertype' S. You have a class X and Y, which are a sub type of S. If you have to change the routine A, when you introduce a new sub type of S, then you violate Liskov's substitution principle. In your example it's for instance the type `ArithmeticQuestion`. A type, which is programmed to work with your type `Question`, won't work with `AirthmeticQuestion`, because you need for instance `getFirstOperand` to work correctly. So what you then have to do is for example to `instanceof` the `Question` type and cast it. There's ways to work around it in a "oo way", but I think that's very important when one is working with subtyping.

### Smaller things

- Some questions to evaluate their operands in the constructor. Those should be passed. Just because of the reason of unit testing: You can't verify the correct operation, if you have no idea, what the operands actually are.
- Not sure if it's standard/convention, but I tend to name my abstract types abstract (`Question` -> `AbstractQuestion`). It often helps.
- `maximumPossibleScore` should be with a getPrefix. Also you might want to consider to calculate it only once.
- `mockExam` should be start with an upper case M.

### Einstein was awesome

Considering the solution to any problem, Einstein said: As easy as possible, but not easier. And to be honest, that's what your solution lacks the most. Here a general (and of course debatable) idea of how it could be implemented much easier:

```
public class Question {
    private String question;
    private String answer;
    private String[] answers;

    private Question(String question, String answer) {
        this(question);
        this.answer = answer;
    }

    private Question(String question, String[] answers) {
        this(question);
        this.answers = answers;
    }

    private Question(String question) {
        this.question = question;
    }

    public boolean isMultipleChoiceQuestions() {
        return answers != null;
    }

    // ...

    public static Question createQuestion(String question, String answer) {
        return new Question(question, answer);
    }

}

public class ExamGenerator {

    public static Exam createEasyExam() {
        // create questions ...

        return new Exam();
    }

    private static Question createMultiplicationQuestion(int factor1, int factor2, int product) {
        return Question.createQuestion("What is blablabla", "put correct answer here");
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :-)

slowy